# IO::Socket::accept works only once if children reaped manually

Tags: perl, sockets, ipc

In the simple echo server below, `accept()` returns `undef` on the second call if I reap children with my own `SIGCHLD` handler instead of letting Perl do it:

```
#!/opt/perl5/bin/perl

use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;
use POSIX qw(WNOHANG);
use strict;
use warnings;

$|=1;

use constant LISTEN_PORT => 9998;

my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new (
                 Proto     => 'tcp',
                 LocalPort => LISTEN_PORT,
                 Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
                 Reuse     => 1);

(! $server) && die "Could not setup server - $!\n";
$server->autoflush(1);


sub reaper {
    while ((my $dead_child = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        print "Reaped PID $dead_child\n";
    }
    $SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper;
};
$SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper;    ## THIS BLOWS
# $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';  ## THIS WORKS

while (my $client = $server->accept()) {
   my $childPid;
   if (! defined($childPid = fork())) {
      die "Could not fork: $!\n";
   }
   if ($childPid == 0) {
      print $client $_ while (<$client>);
      $client->shutdown(1);
      exit();
   } else {
       print "Spawned PID $childPid\n";
   }
   close($client);

}
print "bye\n";
```

In other words:

```
$ ./echoserver.pl
Spawned PID 20953
Reaped PID 20953
bye
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are manually creating all this work using the lowlevel machinery of `IO::Select` etc... rather than using one of the higher-level wrappings of it?

Comment: @LeoNerd, I want a small portable script that doesn't use extra modules in a `$HOME/lib/perl5`; in fact, that's the whole code. Anyway, what's your preferred wrapper?

Comment: if you want something portable, you can fatpack the required modules together into a single file. That way you still get to use justabout anything from CPAN, but know it'll all be bundled into one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your program receives the `SIGCHLD` signal, it is possible for the system call underlying `$server->accept()` to get interrupted. In that case, `accept()` will return `undef` and `$!` and `$!{EINTR}` will be set.

A little more defensive programming is called for in this case. Here's one way:

```
sub robust_accept {
    my $server = shift;
    for (;;) {
        my $client = $server->accept();
        return $client if $client;
        warn "syserror: $!" if !$!{EINTR};
    }
}

while (my $client = robust_accept($server)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot about wicked, tricksy `EINTR` - thanks a lot! What kind of helpful shenanigans is the `IGNORE` handler pulling here?

Comment: `IGNORE` will trap the signal at the OS level and perl will not be aware of it.